# solspace calendar: attach status or category to date specific date inside event

Tags: solspace-calendar

Is it possible to attach separate statuses, categories or some sort of unique hook to each **date** inside the same event when using solspace calendar?

I'm trying to use this for a theater, and the client wants to be able to label dates with stuff like "sold out", and "free" and so on. But these labels have to be attached to a specific date inside the event, not the event itself.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by visiting the **Events** tab in the *Calendar* control panel:
http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/control_panel/#events

In the **Occurrences** column, on the row associated with event you'd like to have occurrences adjusted, click on the *Edit* link. Then click on the occurrence for the given date/time you're wanting to adjust.

It loads up the Publish page and allows you to edit everything except for the Calendar date data itself. Once you Save that entry, it replaces the pseudo occurrence (that assumes data from the parent event entry) with an actual channel entry to store that different data. :)

Comment: That works well, however I've run into another snag. I am now able to change the status and any custom fields such as description of the occurence etc. However if i want to change the time on an occurence i have to leave the checkbox checked to avoid duplicates, but when i do that, I lose any custom status/field info i have previously entered. It seems I can't have it both ways, or am i overlooking something?

Comment: Also, I am unable to delete individual occurrences. I edit the event, click the X and submit the entry, but when I go back in, the occurrence is still there. Why? Ah, I see i can delete an occurrence by not unchecking the box, but then I'm back to having all custom edited occurrences revert to default again...

Comment: If you need to delete an occurrence or change an occurrence's date/time, you'll need to change the original event entry's pattern (eg. using "Select Dates" for the repeat pattern, or creating more than one event entry). The event entry is the original entry that controls the occurrence pattern. Not checking "Remove Edited Occurrences" will result in orphan occurrence data. Leaving it checked makes Calendar rebuild the new occurrence pattern.